# Is it possible that a scalar times a submodule is not a submodule?

Tags: ring-theory, modules

Does there exist a ring $A$ and an $A$-module $X,$ such that for some $a \in A$ and some submodule $Y \subseteq X$, it holds that $aY$ is not a submodule? If $A$ is commutative, this is clearly impossible.

Comment: My guess would be probably, and that it is related to the Ore-property (need to go to lunch now, so if nobody else has answered when I get back, I will think a bit more about it).

Comment: Certainly $aA=Aa$ would be sufficient for $aY$ to be a submodule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy example comes from the ring of $2\times 2$ matrices over $F$, that is: $M_2(F)$.

Let $L$ be the left ideal of matrices of the form $\left\{\begin{bmatrix}x&0\\y&0\end{bmatrix}\mid x,y\in F\right\}$, and let $a=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$.

$L$ is actually a simple left $M_2(F)$ module, but the set $aL$ is a nonzero proper subset of $L$, so it couldn't be a submodule.

Alternatively, you can just verify that with $b=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$, $b(aL)\nsubseteq aL$.

---

Certainly $aX$ is an additive group if $X$ is, so the only problem that could arise is $r(aX)\nsubseteq aX$. As you noted if the ring is commutative this is not an issue, and more generally if $a$ is central, you are also just fine. You'd also be ok if just $aA=Aa$.

Answer (score 3):

This already fails for $X=A$. If $I$ is a left ideal of $A$, then there is no reason why $aI$ should be a left ideal of $A$. Take for instance $A=\mathbb{Z}\langle a,b \rangle$ (free algebra) and $I=Ab$.